# Amazon Selling Partner API 'Too Many Active Keys"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm able to generate a new access token using a refresh token that I have, however when I go to use that access token in a request to SP-API I get a 429 error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Too Many Active Keys",
            "code": "InvalidInput"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find in any documentation exactly what this error means?
I haven't made any requests to SP-API in the last 24 hours so I don't believe that I have been rate-limited.

Answer (score 1):

This is an API issue several are having https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/813

Comment: Is there an answer buried in that GitHub thread? If so, please add that answer to your answer here on SO. Otherwise, your note is probably more appropriate as a comment, not an answer.